# Enum sigleton and static property

Tags: java, enums, singleton

I have SingletonClass class and I want to keep there token property that is required for generic call of Client:

```
public enum SingletonClass {
  INSTANCE;

  private static String token;

  public String callService() {
    return Client.INSTANCE.genericCall(TokenHelper.INSTANCE.getToken(token));
  }
}
```

In my TokenHelper I'm calling REST service to get token if its not populated:

```
public enum TokenHelper {
  INSTANCE;

  public synchronized String getToken(String token) {
    if (token == null || StringUtils.isBlank(token)) {
      token = getNewToken();
    }
    return token;
  }
}
```

How can I store this token on SingletonClass and renew it just once it will expire (I want to keep instead of String token some structure that will hold token value and expired date/time). I'm running that in Tomcat container. Each time I'm calling:

```
SingletonClass.INSTANCE.callService();
```

my token is null but i want to preserve it for 24h.

Comment: You need to ensure the library is shared.  If the library is local to the application it may be re-loaded with each request.

Comment: What do you mean by "ensure the library is shared" ? I have SingletonClass in jar that is added as maven dependency to web app -  so it is in lib for my webapp.

Comment: When you set up a web server you can make a library shared across all applications or have to local to just one.  How you do this depends on the web server you are using.

Comment: Adding to @PeterLawrey comment, the *singleton* instance is a field on a class, and the class is loaded by a ClassLoader, so the singleton is unique per ClassLoader. In web application servers, two web applications may load the same libraries but using different class loaders, so even if the singleton is defined in a single library but this library is loaded twice, then you will have two instances of your *singleton* living in the same JVM instance.